# Host directory and mounted directory in minikube pv & pvc differ

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have created a pv and a pvc, and mount them via helm chart. It all seems to be linked properly, but when I make a change in the hostpath, it does not come through to the container, and if I change the contend of the mounted directory in the container, the change does not appear on the host.

I have ...

- Checked if the pv exists and where it is sourced from
- Checked if the pvc exists
- Checked the pod, if it uses the pvc (it seems to)

Any ideas about what I could have forgotten?

#### Check if PV exist:

```
$ kc get pv
NAME        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
wp-php-pv   2Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    gaph/wp-php-pvc   standard                35m
```

#### Check if PVC exist:

```
$ kc get pvc -n gaph
NAME         STATUS   VOLUME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
wp-php-pvc   Bound    wp-php-pv   2Gi        RWO            standard       35m
```

#### Check origin of PVC

```
$ kc describe pv wp-php-pv -n gaph
Name:            wp-php-pv
Labels:          type=local
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:    standard
Status:          Bound
Claim:           gaph/wp-php-pvc
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        2Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/gaph/php-data
    HostPathType:  
Events:            <none>
```

#### Checking pod

```
$ kc describe pod $WP_POD_NAME -n gaph
Name:             gaph-wp-php-698599cbff-x7hmd
Namespace:        gaph
Priority:         0
Service Account:  gaph-wp-php
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Fri, 06 Jan 2023 15:42:07 +1300
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=gaph-wp
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=php
                  pod-template-hash=698599cbff
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               172.17.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/gaph-wp-php-698599cbff
Containers:
  php:
    Container ID:   docker://f72747594bcd5ae8bbf53b24fecf69f4776f1e7a351d01ef8cdd1e210ebb984e
    Image:          php:8.2-apache
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://php@sha256:739420c858b1f447490c55971416298699678203353ba13e47e4e57b8318c94f
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 06 Jan 2023 15:42:39 +1300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 06 Jan 2023 15:42:08 +1300
      Finished:     Fri, 06 Jan 2023 15:42:38 +1300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Liveness:       http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-rm7xn (ro)
      /var/www/html from wp-php-pv (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  wp-php-pv:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  wp-php-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-rm7xn:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
...
```

#### Checking directory inside pod

... via `kubectl exec ...`

```
/var/www/html# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  6 02:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Dec 21 05:06 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  6 02:47 hellosuperworld.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jan  6 02:42 index.html
```

#### Checking directory on host

```
$ tree /mnt/gaph
/mnt/gaph
└── php-data
    └── index.php
```

This is on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I came across microk8s, installed it, and with the same scripts and configuration the directory mounting to host works perfectly fine there.

Comment: Hi @hey are you sure that you are checking the path in the correct node?. Because the hostpath which is mounted on the pod may depend on which node the pod is running. Check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr766avQ6ss)for more information.

Comment: It seems like you've included a lot of diagnostic output but none of your actual code.  Can you [edit] this question to include a [mcve]?  In general I'd recommend against using `hostPath` volumes: they refer to a specific host directory on whichever node the Pod happens to be running on, but if a Pod is deleted and recreated on a different node, the old data won't follow it, and if a node is destroyed the data will be lost.